# What does this notation mean? $\operatorname{ad}^*_ \mathbf{v} \mathbf{m}$

Tags: notation

Reading [page 45 in this article](https://arxiv.org/abs/1510.00792) I did not understand what the coadjoint operator or dual operator to the Lie bracket meant. It is [defined](https://arxiv.org/abs/1510.00792) as:
$$ \operatorname{ad}^*_ \mathbf{v} \mathbf{m} =  \mathbf{v} \cdot \nabla \mathbf{m} + \nabla \mathbf{v} ^\mathsf{T} \mathbf{m} + \mathbf{m} \operatorname{div} \mathbf{v} $$
I have two guesses, either it is a scalar plus a vector:
$$
\langle v,\nabla m \rangle_g + \langle \nabla v, m \rangle_g + m \operatorname{div} v
$$
(possible in associative algebras?) or it is something like this:
$$
v^j(\nabla_j m^i)+m^j(\nabla_j v^i)+ m^i(\nabla_j v^j)
$$
which I am having a little hard time to write without using einstein notation.

It is mentioned in the context of using the divergence theorem. Probably the factor related to the Lie bracket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All terms are vector fields, ie $(1,0)$-tensors. For each $(p,q)$-tensor $X$, page 33 of your link defines $\nabla X$ to denote the covariant derivative of $X$, which is a $(p,q+1)$-tensor. Wikipedia gives an [explicit formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_derivative#Coordinate_description) in coordinates using Christoffel symbols. I'm assuming $\cdot^T$ denotes transposing a tensor with respect to the metric; for a $(1,1)$-tensor $X$ this means
$$
  (X^T)_a^b=X_c^dg_{ad}g^{bc}.
$$
Thus in coordinates we have
$$
  (\mathrm{ad}_{\mathbf v}^*\mathbf m)^a=\mathbf v^b(\nabla\mathbf m)_b^a+(\nabla\mathbf v^T)_b^a\mathbf m^b+(\mathrm{div}\,\mathbf v)\mathbf m^a.
$$
This is the dual of the Lie bracket with respect to the inner product
$$
  \int_{\mathcal S}\langle\mathbf v,\mathbf w\rangle\mu_g
$$
where $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is the pairing given by the metric $g$. That is,
$$
  \int_{\mathcal S}\langle\mathrm{ad}_{\mathbf v}^*\mathbf w,\mathbf u\rangle\mu_g=-\int_{\mathcal S}\langle\mathbf w,\mathrm{ad}_{\mathbf v}\mathbf u\rangle\mu_g
$$
(I'm not sure why there is a sign change here; maybe this is a physics convention? Also I'm assuming $\mathcal S$ has no boundary). To see this, note that
$$
  \partial_ag_{bc}=\Gamma_{cba}+\Gamma_{bca}
    =g_{cd}\Gamma^d{}_{ba}+g_{bd}\Gamma^d{}_{ca}.
$$
Hence
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
  \mathbf v(\langle\mathbf w,\mathbf u\rangle)
    &=&\mathbf v^a\partial_a(\mathbf w^b\mathbf u^cg_{bc})\\
    &=&\mathbf v^a(\partial_a\mathbf w^b)\mathbf u^cg_{bc}
      +\mathbf v^a\mathbf w^b(\partial_a\mathbf u^c)g_{bc}
      +\mathbf v^a\mathbf w^b\mathbf u^c(\partial_ag_{bc})\\
    &=&\mathbf v^a(\partial_a\mathbf w^b)\mathbf u^cg_{bc}
      +\mathbf u^a\mathbf w^b(\partial_a\mathbf v^c)g_{bc}
      +[\mathbf v,\mathbf u]^c\mathbf w^bg_{bc}\\
    &&{}+\mathbf v^a\mathbf w^b\mathbf u^c
      (g_{cd}\Gamma^d{}_{ba}+g_{bd}\Gamma^d{}_{ca})\\
    &=&\mathbf v^a(\partial_a\mathbf w^b)\mathbf u^cg_{bc}
      +\mathbf u^a\mathbf w^b(\partial_a\mathbf v^c)g_{bc}
      +\langle\mathbf w,[\mathbf v,\mathbf u]\rangle\\
    &&{}+\mathbf v^a\mathbf w^d\mathbf u^cg_{cb}\Gamma^b{}_{da}
      +\mathbf v^d\mathbf w^b\mathbf u^ag_{bc}\Gamma^c{}_{ad}\\
    &=&\mathbf v^a\mathbf u^cg_{bc}
        (\partial_a\mathbf w^b+\Gamma^b{}_{da}\mathbf w^d)
      +\mathbf u^a\mathbf w^bg_{bc}
        (\partial_a\mathbf v^c+\Gamma^c{}_{da}\mathbf v^d)
      +\langle\mathbf w,[\mathbf v,\mathbf u]\rangle\\
    &=&\mathbf v^a\mathbf u^cg_{bc}(\nabla\mathbf w)_a^b
      +\mathbf u^a\mathbf w^bg_{bc}(\nabla\mathbf v)_a^c
      +\langle\mathbf w,[\mathbf v,\mathbf u]\rangle\\
    &=&\mathbf u^cg_{bc}(\mathbf v\cdot\nabla\mathbf w)^b
      +\mathbf u^a\mathbf w^b(\nabla\mathbf v^T)_b^eg_{ea}
      +\langle\mathbf w,[\mathbf v,\mathbf u]\rangle\\
    &=&\langle\mathbf v\cdot\nabla\mathbf w
      +\nabla\mathbf v^T\mathbf w,\mathbf u\rangle
      +\langle\mathbf w,[\mathbf v,\mathbf u]\rangle.
\end{eqnarray*}$$
Thus
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
  \int_{\mathcal S}
    \langle\mathrm{ad}_{\mathbf v}^*\mathbf w,\mathbf u\rangle
    +\langle\mathbf w,\mathrm{ad}_{\mathbf v}\mathbf u\rangle\mu_g
    \hspace{-30mm}\\
    &=&\int_{\mathcal S}\langle
      \mathbf v\cdot\nabla\mathbf w
      +\nabla\mathbf v^T\mathbf w
      +(\mathrm{div}\,\mathbf v)\mathbf w,\mathbf u\rangle
      +\langle\mathbf w,[\mathbf v,\mathbf u]\rangle\mu_g\\
    &=&\int_{\mathcal S}
      \mathbf v(\langle\mathbf w,\mathbf u\rangle)
      +\langle\mathbf w,\mathbf u\rangle\mathrm{div}\,\mathbf v\,\mu_g\\
    &=&\int_{\mathcal S}
      \mathrm{div}\,(\langle\mathbf w,\mathbf u\rangle\mathbf v)\,\mu_g\\
    &=&0.
\end{eqnarray*}$$

Comment: Thank you so much for being so detailed! Took away some of my hopeless feeling. The last step where divergence is set to zero, is there some kind of boundary condition used there? Otherwise I'd feel happy to just keep the divergence term.

Comment: @Emil Yes if $\mathcal S$ has a boundary then some boundary condition would be needed. I didn't read the whole paper but I guess on p44 where this is applied, probably the variation $\zeta$ is supposed to vanish on the boundary?